# Java : Is there any way to put a String into List<Integer>?

Tags: java

Interview Question :

The `String`object could be any format, not only `numbers` representation.

Comment: `List ilist = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ilist.add ("aString");`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it's **possible** with casting because of type erasure, but it's a **Bad Idea™** and code using the list in the *normal* way after doing so will throw `ClassCastException`.

But it's *possible*, in that this code runs:

```
List<Integer> l = new ArrayList<Integer>();
((List)l).add("hello");
```

That works because by casting to the raw `List` type rather than the parameterized `List<Integer>` type, we bypass the compilation check; and at runtime, the type parameter information is (mostly) gone thanks to type erasure and so the string successfully gets added to the list.

But again, any code with a `List<Integer>` reference to the list that's written normally (e.g., according to the `List<Integer>` contract) will blow up when it tries to access that entry, because the code will try to cast the `String` to `Integer`.

Looking a bit more in-depth:

```
List<Integer> l = new ArrayList<Integer>();
((List)l).add("hello");
System.out.println("Added successfully");

Iterator it = l.iterator();              // Old-fashioned raw iterator works
while (it.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println(it.next());
}

for (Object o : l) {                     // Enhanced for with Object works
    System.out.println(o);
}

for (Integer i : l) {                    // But this throws when it reaches the
    System.out.println(i);               // String, because String cannot be cast
}                                        // to Integer
```